# Update executes without error, but doesn't update the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

So I'm still teaching myself MVC and I'm now trying to update a user record.

I have the following code:

```
// The Controller:
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(User model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            User u = new User();
            u.Update(model);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
    }

// The Model:
    public void Update(User u)
    {
        var user = GetUserById(u.UserId);
        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

This code all executes perfectly fine, but it doesn't actually update the database.

The values below appear to be the values exactly from the database, not the ones from the View. Why this is, I can't understand.

[image: Debugging]

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you actually updating anything in the user entity that will force an update in the DB? Unless I am reading it wrong, you are getting the user and then updating it, where are the changes?

Comment: Agreed with @ChrisBint, you are not changing anything on the user entity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you forgot to update your field. 
In this case you can use `TryUpdateModel();` to update your fields.
You should have something like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        User u = new User();
        u.Update(model);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Users");
}

public void Update(User u)
{
    var user = GetUserById(u.UserId);
    TryUpdateModel(user); // You forgot this 
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use TryUpdateModel() or can I update the properties separately (i.e. `user.Username = u.Username`)?

Comment: You can do one of them. `TryUpdateModel()` actually copies every property with the same name.

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find TryUpdateModel() but this form in particular is only meant to update some of the info so I updated each of those values as per my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the following code from your Controller and passing in the User generated from the view model.

```
public void Update(User u)
    {
        var user = GetUserById(u.UserId);
        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

However, the code above attempts to retrieve the user based on it's ID and then simply performs an update, without actually changing any data.